# Training Custom Model on Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-ml, custom-training

I have couple of of questions regarding training custom model:

1. I am using prebuilt Google image and everything is running fine, but I am not able to get the artifacts in "local-package-path" folder.
2. I am using my own container and want to understand that if the code and data should be inside the container or can pass it at run time.If we can pass it at run time, how do I do that?

Comment: 1. EExporting the artifacts will depend on what you arfe using, check this dicumentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/exporting-model-artifacts). To access your data, it generally is on google cloud storage and you send it via runtime using the variables described [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/using-managed-datasets#access_a_dataset_from_your_training_application).

Answer (score 0):

Follow [Vertex AI:Training and serving a custom model](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/vertex_custom_training_prediction#0) example which you can watch [Build a custom ML model with Vertex AI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2CJL3tQasw) as a demo.